# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Interjektionen "o" und "oh"?

Tags: difference, meaning, interjection

Es gibt in deutschen zwei phonetisch sehr ähnliche Ausrufewörter (Interjektionen): `o` und mit Dehnungs-h: `oh`.

Beispiele:

> O du fröhliche ([Weihnachtslied](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_du_fr%C3%B6hliche))
>
> Oh, das tut mir leid!

Gibt es einen Unterschied in der Verwendung und/oder in der Bedeutung der beiden Wörter oder sind die beliebig austauschbar?

Comment: Trotz der Bedeutungsgleichheit schlage ich vor "oh" zu verwenden. Zum einen fragt man sich dann nicht, ob ein Schreibfehler vorliegt, da es nur sehr wenige einbuchstabige Wörter im Deutschen gibt (mir fällt überhaupt keins ein ;). Zum anderen läuft der Leser nicht Gefahr den Buchstaben "O" mit der Zahl "0" (Null) zu verwechseln. Auch wenn das in Deinem Beispiel unwahrscheinlich ist :)

Comment: @JohnSmithers Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob *O schöne Frau!* und *Oh schöne Frau!"* nicht verschiedene Dinge vermitteln. *"oh"* drückt für mich Überraschung (oder ähnliche Gefühle) aus, während *"o"* eine Art Huldigung vermittelt. Oder bilde ich mir das nur ein?

Comment: @JohnSmithers PS: Im Englischen gibt es anscheinend den Unterschied: http://weblogs.baltimoresun.com/news/mcintyre/blog/2011/03/uhoh.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Unterschied ist semantisch und grammatikalisch:

Oh, stets mit einem Komma vom Rest des Satzes getrennt, ist eine Interjektion und wird als Ausdruck der Überraschung, Erkenntnis etc. (unwillkürlich) verwendet. ("Oh, das wusste ich nicht!", "Oh! Das tut mir leid.")

O, stets in Verbindung mit einem weiteren Wort ohne Komma dazwischen, ist eine Exklamation, ein (bewusster) Ausruf, eine Anrufung usw. ("O nein!", "Vergib mir, o Herr!")

Eine Gemeinsamkeit besteht darin, dass beides mit einem Ausrufezeichen abgeschlossen wird.

Da das heutige Sprachverständnis generell, auch in akademischen Kreisen, ein unreflektiertes ist, wird 'oh' oftmals (fälschlicherweise) synonym zu 'o' verwendet, welches heute kaum noch einer kennt. Der Rechtschreibduden ist übrigens seit 1996 nicht mehr verbindlich und das ist bei seinem rapiden Qualitätsverlust aus sprachwissenschaftlicher Sicht ein Segen.

Comment: +1 für "stets in Verbindung mit einem weiteren Wort ohne Komma dazwischen"

Answer (score 3):

Du selbst zeigst in deinen Beispielen schon den Unterschied:

> *O du fröhliche Weihnachtszeit...*  = direkte Anrede der Weihnachtszeit

*O* entstammt dem lateinischen und griechischen  [Vokativ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokativ). Es war damals zur direkten Anrede zwingend erforderlich. Heute findet man es noch in alten Kirchenliedern und in der Poesie.

Dagegen:

> *Oh, das tut mir leid!*  = Interjektion, Ausruf

Der typische, heute noch ständig verwendet Ausruf zur Betonung von Überraschung (oder Sarkasmus).

Answer (score 1):

Wie der Duden-Link in [Kevins Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/gibt-es-einen-unterschied-zwischen-den-interjektionen-o-und-oh/3413#3413) ausführt, wird das einzelne "O" meist in Verbindung mit anderen Wörtern geschrieben. Der Ursprung könnte aus Anrufungen wie "O Herr" oder "O Jesu" stammen, wo das "O" als Zusatz zum lateinischen [Vokativ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokativ) Verwendung fand und in der Übersetzung überlebte.

Diese Ausdrücke werden auch oft als Ausruf der Überraschung verwendet. Diesen Ausruf verkürzte man dann auf ein einfaches "O". Und da einbuchstabige Wörter im Deutschen nicht gebräuchlich sind, wurde daraus "Oh".

Man könnte damit einen Bedeutungsunterschied konstruieren, daß "O Gott" bei der Anrufung/beim Gebet verwendet wird und "Oh Gott" beim überraschten Ausruf. Ich halte diese Unterscheidung aber nicht für weitläufig bekannt und kenne niemanden, der sie verwendet.

Für eine ausführliche Behandlung des Themas empfehle ich den [Belles-Lettres-Artikel](http://www.belleslettres.eu/blog/oh-o-interjektion.php).

Comment: Der Link ist toll, aber irgendwie sagt er etwas anderes als diese Antwort und eher das, was die anderen Antworten aussagen.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt also keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden in Bedeutung oder Aussprache. In Verbindung mit anderen Wörtern wird's oft ohne "h" geschrieben.

([Duden entry for "oh"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oh))

Comment: Hmm, mir kommt aber *O, ich habe mich verwählt.* seltsam vor. Kann ich das wirklich verwenden?

Comment: Nach Duden, ja. Ich finde auch vielleicht öfter "O je" aber "Oh, das habe ich verpasst" aber beide Formen sind technisch zulässig.

Comment: Da bin ich anderer Meinung. *Oh* ist eine Interjektion, die in einen Satz eingefügt wird. *O* - richtig verwendet - ist immer Teil einer Anrede/Anrufung: *O Heiland, reiß' die Himmel auf...O Erd', schlag' aus, schlag aus, o Erd'!*